# How to trim duplicated values in a string KQL?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have the following data sample:

```
let data = datatable(Name:string, Value:string)
            [
                "Device_1", "60.12.12 %",
                "Device_2", "40.12.12 %",
                "Device_3", "50.12.12 %",
                "Device_4", "48.33.33 %"
            ];
```

As you can see in the Value column, the values after the decimal points are duplicated.

How can we trim the second decimal point and the values after it ?

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish :-)

P.S.
Added some use-cases to test it

```
let data = datatable(Name:string, Value:string)
[ 
    "Device_1"  ,"60.12.12 %"
   ,"Device_2"  ,"40.12.12 %"
   ,"Device_3"  ,"50.12.12 %"
   ,"Device_4"  ,"48.33.33 %"
   ,"Device_5"  ,"48.11.22.33 %"
   ,"Device_6"  ,"48.11.22 %"
   ,"Device_7"  ,"48.11 %"
   ,"Device_8"  ,"48 %"
   ,"Device_9"  ,".11 %"
   ,"Device_10" ,".11"
   ,"Device_11" ,".11.22"
];
data
| extend replace_regex(Value, @"(\.\d+).*", @"\1 %")
```

| Name | Value | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device_1 | 60.12.12 % | 60.12 % |
| Device_2 | 40.12.12 % | 40.12 % |
| Device_3 | 50.12.12 % | 50.12 % |
| Device_4 | 48.33.33 % | 48.33 % |
| Device_5 | 48.11.22.33 % | 48.11 % |
| Device_6 | 48.11.22 % | 48.11 % |
| Device_7 | 48.11 % | 48.11 % |
| Device_8 | 48 % | 48 % |
| Device_9 | .11 % | .11 % |
| Device_10 | .11 | .11 % |
| Device_11 | .11.22 | .11 % |

[Fiddle](https://%20https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/demo12.westus/databases/GitHub?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3XQXwuCMBAA8Hdh3%20EYBFoy3PyTFUEPPffYS0asPEQwCVvhQx%20%20OZUobRyMu98dG1egglQqCWtzKXku0N7JKy7vqsrLzIW9LB595hDrAMQCfegWn/kFT5wCuDTyGBc6YEINuz0Lw8E/9g2H/zhop2Pm%20zoGHPbMORNirCP66hjw/MMDizsbwMLA2Aj3aCu/dd7V9R80HVfEapZNrBdgrbBMocJbIXVnhRnWtlm5CxtqJyxJZw6b0iZLmhedN1M5txKyAQAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = datatable(Name:string, Value:string)
            [
                "Device_1", "60.12.12 %",
                "Device_2", "40.12.12 %",
                "Device_3", "50.12.12 %",
                "Device_4", "48.33.33 %"
            ];
data
| parse kind=regex Value with Percent:real
```

| Name | Value | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device_1 | 60.12.12 % | 60.12 |
| Device_2 | 40.12.12 % | 40.12 |
| Device_3 | 50.12.12 % | 50.12 |
| Device_4 | 48.33.33 % | 48.33 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/demo12.westus/databases/GitHub?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVFISSxJVLAFUyWJSTmpGn6JualWxSVFmXnpOgphiTmlMJ4mL5cCEohG5YKAkktqWWZyaryhko6CkpmBnqERECmoKungVmoEUmpClFJjkFJTopSagE210DM2BiKgUlSVsda8XCD/8nLVKBQkFhWnKmRn5qXYFqWmp1ZAfKxQnlmSoRCQWpScmldiVZSamAMA9rZ1ASsBAAA=)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But is there a way to use extract_all instead of parse ?
I need to make sure to keep % in the end as mentioned in the expected result. I don't know if trim or trim_end can help in this case ?

Comment: You seriously want to store percentage as string? I was trying to save you from this mistake... :-)

Comment: The problem is that I have a platform which creates a table out of the values obtained. But I need to visualize the unit inside and the only way to do that is to have the column as string. I know it is ridiculous but this is how it should be done haha